# How to pass different parameters through a variable for an api request

Tags: python

I would like to pass different id to send through a request to an api. The api address is this (I'm doing it in python):

```
https://myaccountname.mymarket.com.br/api/catalog/pvt/getimages/{productId}/file
```

The address above asks the user to provide the Id of what he wants to pass. But I would like to send, within an excel spreadsheet, the URL address of the images to associate with their respective id's

If I separate by commas it doesn't work. And I can not think of a solution or if there is no way to do it the way I would like.

#### I'm editing my question and passing the code

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "APPKEY": "APPKEY",
    "APPTOKEN": "TOKEN" 
}

for s, name in enumerate(spreedsheet["Name"]):  
  Id = str(int(spreedsheet.loc[s,"ProductId"]))  
  img_Url = str(spreedsheet.loc[s,"Url"])
  
  payloads = {"Name": name, "ProductId": Id,  "Url": img_Url}

  response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payloads)  
  response = response.json()
```

In this code I am reading each row and associating the column. In the Name column, line 1 will have the name of the image, next to it will have the Id and then the url. Below, the same logic follows. The logic of going through excel works. I just can't think of how to specify in the url that there are more than one Id

Comment: I think you are going to have to explain with an [edit] what you are trying to do because it is unclear what the question is. Example: does "id" mean "productID" in the URL? What does an "image" have to do with any of this? Please clarify _in the question_ what you are doing, what you tried, and show what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing additional information inside de [**body**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/body) of your HTTP request

Comment: I don't get. 
should I put the variables that would be replaced by the Id inside the body?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code where you are handling that API  request